# How to pick yesterday date in spark sql for a date in Unix Date Format?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, date, unix, format

How to pick yesterday date in spark sql for a date in Unix Date Format? Example : Select * from **** where date in (DateinUnixFormat)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table called `test`, you can add another column called `yesterday` that holds yesterday's date as unix timestamp through:

```
spark.sql("select *,to_unix_timestamp(date_add(current_date(), -1),'yyyy-MM-dd') as yesterday from test")
```

Final output:

```
+------------+----------+
|        test| yesterday|
+------------+----------+
|        test|1662588000|
+------------+----------+
```

Good luck!